# Prove statement about localization of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, localization

I'm trying to solve the following problem, but I don't know how to do it and it would be great if someone could give me some hints:

> For elements $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ of a commutative ring $A$, show that the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1.) $(f_1, \ldots , f_n) = A$
>
> 2.) For each nonzero module $M$ over $A$, at least one of the localized modules $M_{f_i}$ is nonzero.

I know that $M=0 \Leftrightarrow M_{p}=0$ for $p \subset A$ prime $\Leftrightarrow M_{m} = 0$ for $m \subset A$ maximal.

But for that, I would have to show that the $f_i$ is prime/maximal $\forall i$. And I guess that 1.) gives somehow a hint for this, but I'm not able to put this together. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $f_i$s have no reason to be prime. Here's a hint:

$M$ is non-zero if and only if there's a $\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec}A$ such that $M_{\mathfrak p}\ne \{0\}$.

Now, consider the Zariski topology on $\operatorname{Spec}A$:
$$V\bigl((f_1,\dots,f_n)\bigr)=\smash{\bigcap_{i=1}^n} V(f_i),$$
and note $\;(f_1,\dots,f_n)=A \iff \displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^n V(f_i)=\varnothing$, so there's an $f_i$ such that $f_i\notin\mathfrak p$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: That means, if $f_i \not\in \mathfrak{p}$ then $f_i \in A - \mathfrak{p}$ and since $M_{p} = (A - \mathfrak{p})^{-1}M$, $f_i \in M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ which means, that $M_\mathfrak{p}$ is non-zero. 
Is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly: we take  a $\mathfrak p$ such that $M_{\mathfrak p}\ne 0$ anyway. But observe $M_{\mathfrak p}$ is a localisation of $M_{f_i}$ as well.

Comment: Ah, that hint helped me a lot! Thank you :) From here, I can take it further.